# Could argument type declariation be moved into function body?

Tags: c, function, definition, function-declaration

That is, some kind of the following:

```
void t(m)
{int m;}
```

This code does not compile.
I mostly use Fortran, which uses the above style.

Comment: Is there any reason at all that you want to do this?

Comment: Different languages use different conventions.  Trying to force the conventions of one language onto another generally doesn't lead to happiness.

Comment: @Broman  No real reason to do this, just for curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is the *obsolete* declaration style as in the following,

```
void t(m)
  int m;
{
    (void)m;
}
```

however this is never (should never be, as @JonathanLeffler notes) used in modern code.

I recommend the book "C A Reference Manual" by Harbison and Steele for things like this.

Comment: That is the K&R (pre-standard) C notation for a function.  It should never be used in modern code; this style has been marked obsolescent since the first C standard was issued.

Comment: The modern style is compact and is obviously better than Fortan style since it reduces repeat (an argument does not need to be mentioned twice).

Comment: @YoujunHu right, I don't think anyone would argue with that